# python program freezes after trying pyautogui.pixel(x,y),why?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
def rpix(x,y):
    print("printing")
    pix = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
    print("pix--")
    messagebox.showinfo("pixel",f"pixel: {pix}")
    print("done")
```

its does not get past defining pix, I have tryed everything i can think of. Why is this not working?

Comment: That's strange, it's working properly here. How are you calling this function? Can you paste the full code please?

Comment: I cant paste the full code, its too large. I tryed to int() it and it still freezes up on me. Im just going to try and rewrite the code